# Using 2 different 7 segment display to display a 4-bit 0 to 15 counter

Tags: verilog

I am trying to display a 4-bit counter on 2 different 7 segment display on the basys 3 fpga. The basys 3 fpga comes with 4 different 7 segment display with different anode but common cathodes to light us the display led. I am unable to display two different values at the displays.

Eventually, I need to build a 0000 to 9999 counter using all 4 different 7 display segments, so using hex counting will not work for me.

Please help.

Code:

```
module counter(

input press, 
input clock,
output reg [6:0] seg,
output reg [3:0] an 
);

reg [3:0]count = 4'b0000;
wire pulse;

// Don't need to worry about the exact code in this function call

singlepulse sp(clock,press,pulse);

always @(posedge pulse) begin
count <= count + 1;
end

integer k;
reg [3:0]ones=0;
reg [3:0]tenths=0;

//convert binary to BCD

always @( count )
    begin

    ones = 4'd0;
    tenths = 4'd0;

    for ( k=4; k>=0; k=k-1 ) begin
    if( tenths>=5 ) tenths=tenths+3;
    if( ones>=5 ) ones=ones+3;
    tenths=tenths<<1;
    tenths[0]=ones[3];
    ones=ones<<1;
    ones[0]=count[k];
    end    

end

always @(posedge clock) begin

// Here is the problem, if I let an=4'b1110 only the first display will light up
// If I let an=4'b1100 both display light shows the same number instead of the correct number
// How should I make it such that both displays shows different number at the same time?
case (ones)
0 : seg=7'b100_0000;
1 : seg=7'b111_1001;
2 : seg=7'b010_0100;
3 : seg=7'b011_0000;
4 : seg=7'b001_1001;
5 : seg=7'b001_0010;
6 : seg=7'b000_0010;
7 : seg=7'b111_1000;
8 : seg=7'b000_0000;
9 : seg=7'b001_0000;
endcase

case (tenths)
0 : seg=7'b100_0000;
1 : seg=7'b111_1001;
2 : seg=7'b010_0100;
3 : seg=7'b011_0000;
4 : seg=7'b001_1001;
5 : seg=7'b001_0010;
6 : seg=7'b000_0010;
7 : seg=7'b111_1000;
8 : seg=7'b000_0000;
9 : seg=7'b001_0000;
endcase

end

endmodule  // counter
```

Thanks

Comment: One immediate mistake is that you need two different values of  `seg` in single block through different case statements. The current code will overwrite the *ones* value of `seg`. Either use two output variables or use `seg[0]` for ones position  and `seg[1]` for tens position. This may or may not be the cause of error, but it's certainly a logical error.

Comment: I am aware of the error, but however basys 3 only has 7 inputs for the cathodes and 4 inputs for the anode to control the all 4 different 7 segment displays. I had only learned verilog for a month and don't know other better ways to approach the problem

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a logic design problem, rather than a Verilog problem. I think your solution is to *time multiplex*. In other words, you need to drive each 7-segment display for a short time in turn, sufficiently fast so that the eye cannot perceive this. You'll need a circuit that drives the `seg` outputs differently for each `an` output and rotates this very quickly.